# Java drawing weird visual artifacts/bug

Tags: java, swing

I am beginner in java programming. We were given a task, to do some algorithms. I got Sierpinski Triangle. I had an idea to create a 2D array and store the values, 0 = white rectangle, 1 = blue rectangle. I had big trouble to draw it (never had any experience with swing/awt). I finally did it but on the end of the drawing there is weird visual bug. It is not ending but the lines are still continuing.

I have no idea why is it like that.

Here is my code:

`Okno` class that extends `JPanel`:

```
/*
 * To change this license header, choose License Headers in Project Properties.
 * To change this template file, choose Tools | Templates
 * and open the template in the editor.
 */
package newpackage;

import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Graphics2D;
import java.util.Arrays;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;

/**
 *
 * @author Juraj
 */
class Okno extends JPanel {

    // value = 1 is blue rectangle, value 0 = white rectangle
    public static int n = 500;
    public static int[][] tabulka = new int[n][n]; //creating 2D array

    public static void inicializaciaTabulky(){
        for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) { // initialization of 2D array (first column and first row = 1)
            tabulka[0][i] = 1;
            tabulka[i][0] = 1;
        }
    }

    // filling the rest of the array; if the cell above and cell to the left are the same value, e.g.
    // value of 1 or 0, then it is 0, everything else is 1
    public static void doplnenieTabulky() {
        for (int i = 1; i < n; i++) {
            for (int j = 1; j < n; j++) {
                if (tabulka[i-1][j] == 1 && tabulka[i][j-1] == 1 || 
                    tabulka[i-1][j] == 0 && tabulka[i][j-1] == 0) {
                    tabulka[i][j] = 0;
                } else {
                    tabulka[i][j] = 1;
                }
            }
        }
    }

    // drawing rectangles; if the value is 1 = blue rectangle, value 0 = white rectangle
    private void vykreslenie(Graphics g){
        Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D) g;

        for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < n; j++) {
                switch(tabulka[i][j]) {
                    case 0: 
                        g.setColor(Color.white);
                        g.drawRect(i, j, 50, 50);
                        break;
                    case 1: 
                        g.setColor(Color.blue);
                        g.drawRect(i, j, 50, 50);
                        break;
                }
            }
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
        super.paintComponent(g);
        vykreslenie(g);
    }
}
```

`Trojuholnik` class that extends `JFrame`:

```
public class Trojuholnik extends JFrame {  
    public Trojuholnik() {
        initUI();
    }

    private void initUI() {
        setSize(800, 600);
        setTitle("Sierpinski Triangle");
        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        add(new Okno());
        setLocationRelativeTo(rootPane);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                Trojuholnik trojuholnik = new Trojuholnik();
                trojuholnik.setVisible(true);
                Okno.inicializaciaTabulky();
                Okno.doplnenieTabulky();
                System.out.println(Arrays.deepToString(Okno.tabulka));
            }
        });
    }
}
```

The current result looks like this:

[image: result of code]

Comment: I've added a screenshot of the current result. If it looks different on your computer, then feel free, to include a better/correct picture.

Comment: @Tom Thanks for editing. It looks same as the picture you posted.I couldnt post the picture because of not having enough of reputation.

Comment: In that case, just add a link to the picture. Someone with sufficient rights will include that picture.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First of all some basic suggestions:

Don't create a class that extends JFrame. You are not adding new functionality to the frame so you should just be adding your panel to a frame. So the basic code in your run() method should be something like:

```
JFrame frame = new JFrame();
frame.setTitle("Sierpinski Triangle");
frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
frame.add( new Okno());
frame.pack();
frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
frame.setVisible(true);
```

Don't use static variables and methods in your Okno class. Just create a constructor for your class and initialize the array in the constructor.

When doing custom painting you should be overriding the `getPreferredSize()` method of you class to return the size of the component because each component should know its own size. Note how I changed the above code to use the `pack()` method. Now the frame will be resized properly. So you would add something like the following to your Okno class:

```
@Override
public Dimension getPreferredSize()
{
    return new Dimension(500, 500);
}
```

Regarding the painting problem. I don't really know what the algorithm is doing, but I suspect that the problem is that your array has 500 values, but the painting of the Rectangle is using a size of 50, so effectively the size of your panel is 550x550 not 500x500 which causes the artifacts.

I think the solution is to simply draw with a rectangle size of (1, 1). At least the drawing looks the same to me.

Comment: Thank you very much sir. I will redo the code with your suggestions above. I had no idea, why the change of the rectangle size(1, 1) helped it but now it works. Maybe the clipping at the end of the panel was causing the error as you first suggested. I changed it and now it works. Thank you once again.